# Java Nested Foreach SLOW When Casting

Tags: java, performance, loops, nested

I am writing an exchange system in Java, but I seem to have run into a crippling performance issue.

The following code is where execution becomes **VERY** slow:

```
    outer:
    for(ArrayList<Offer> listSell : sellOffers.values()) {
        for(Offer sellOffer : listSell) {
            ArrayList<Offer> listBuy = buyOffers.get(getStorageHash(sellOffer));
            if(listBuy == null)
                continue outer;
            for(int i = 0; i < listBuy.size(); i++) {
                Offer buyOffer = listBuy.get(i);
                //todo - handle exchange
            }
        }
    }
```

After looking deeper into this, I found that the following line seems to be the issue:

```
                Offer buyOffer = listBuy.get(i);
```

If I change this line to the following, it will no longer cripple execution time:

```
                Object buyOffer = listBuy.get(i);
```

Therefore, when casting on the object from *listBuy* there is a major delay in execution. Is there any work around for this? I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those casts don't happen directly in front of you, and I legitimately doubt that the cast is what's slowing you down as opposed to the triple-nested loop you're running.

Comment: Why are you switching from foreach loop (`for(Offer sellOffer : listSell)`) to plain for loop (`for (int i=0; i<listBuy.size(); i++)`)? Why not use foreach on the third loop too?

Comment: Loop label (`outer`) is discouraged, and should only be used where needed. You don't need it, because using `break` will get you same result.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas for the outer tip.
Also I was using the plain loop simply to test the cast theory.

Answer (score 3):

You measure it wrong.

When you write `Object buyOffer = listBuy.get(i);` the inner loop has no side effects, and JIT compiler eliminates the loop completely.

With `Offer buyOffer` JIT is not allowed to remove the loop, because every list access now has a possible side effect of throwing `ClassCastException`.

Type check is a fast operation, I doubt that it is a bottleneck in your application. Most likely the algorithm itself is suboptimal since it has a cubic complexity.